# changing keyboard layout on a Thai-laptop - into German

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-language

I would like to get rid of win8 and install ubuntu on my new Laptop. There is one question I have regarding the Keyboard. I bought this Laptop in Thailand and the keyboard is Thai/American. For me it is necessary to change the Keyboard layout into German layout and switch between Thai and German. Is this possible with ubuntu?
Thanks a lot...
Elke

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, at the install you are asked wich keyboard layouts 
you want to use,or you go into the system setting click on keybord at the bottom of the window there is a button saying keyboard layout or likewise click it, in this new window at the bottomthere is a plus sign if you click it you can select additional layouts.

If there is more than one keyboard layout selected in thesettings then a little keyboard symbol appears in the upper right of your screen, you can easily switch layouts at any moment even if you are not logged in.